# Python 3.5 - Django -- virtualenv on shared folder -- Windows to Mac

Tags: python, django, windows, macos

I've created a virtualenv in Windows 7 on a shared folder so that I can work on it with other colleagues.
I set up the virtualenv to have python3.5 and installed Django but when I activate it from my mac I see python 2.7 and I cannot run the runserver command and I get this error as if Django was not installed.

```
(WebSite) UNKNOWN:myenv user$ python3 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

I'm fairly sure it could be an easy fix, but cannot find a guide online that explains if Windows and Mac are "compatibles".

Comment: It's not a good idea to share virtual environments between machines. Create a different virtual env for each machine. You can use a [requirements file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) to make sure you install the same packages in each virtual env.

Comment: ...also not between operating systems, Python versions, Python implementations, architectures and users.

Comment: Thanks! In general then what is best practice if there is more than one person involved in the development?

Comment: Everyone creates his own VE.

Comment: I suspect OP needs to learn about version control systems.

Comment: true story :) will definitely start using version control. Thanks!